# Any simple C++ game showing on DOS window? for example Bowling game, etc

Tags: c++

Need a simple C++ game project as semester project. Thats it. I want a detailed project which makes it easy to let me explain it in front of teachers.

Comment: Are you telling us to make your homework?

Comment: Recommendations are not a good fit for StackOverflow, which may be the reasons for the down votes.

Comment: We don't do your homework for you ( at least, not when you just just tell us to do it all by ourselves )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't even

Answer (score 2):

Since you have asked for a simple game, I will give you one.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int i;
    cout<<"Enter a number ( hint 42 ) \n";
    cin>>i;
    if( i == 42 )
      cout<<" Yay, you win\n";
    else
      cout<<" You lose \n";
    return 0;
}
```

I don't think a game can get simpler than that. You win the game if you enter 42, else, you lose.

Explaining this is quite simple.

First, using `cout` , the program outputs " Enter a number ( hint 42 ) " . Next, it accepts a value from the user and stores it in the variable `i` using `cin`.

After that, using the `if` statement, it checks if the value of `i` is equal to `42` and if the result is true, then it outputs " Yay, you win ", otherwise, the else statement is executed and it outputs " You lose ".

The program will then exit with return value `0`.

Well, that ends the detailed explanation.

Comment: Shame you have no error checking, and did not initialise `i`. Not to mention strange formatting and that `return 0` is redundant.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit , good point. I just made it as simple as possible so that the OP can explain it easily.

Comment: Now he'll be able to explain how it is not fit for purpose.

Comment: @ArunA.S `You loose`  Umm, you spelled "lose" wrong.  Using `loose` can have several unflattering meanings.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , I had never noticed that difference before. Thanks a lot. After Googling for a while, I found out that I have been using it the wrong way my entire life.

Comment: @ArunA.S That's ok.  A lot of people confuse the two when spelling, but not speaking.